# String to array select only elements with a length of 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Lets suppose i have this string:

```
 01234  ; 0123;0424 09234
```

How can i split these string by two arguments `' '` and `';'`,

Trim the single elements

and next, select only these elements of the array who have a length of `5`

So that at the end it returns this array:

```
["01234","09234"]
```

My biggest problem with this task is that i dont know how i should split the string because always when i do:

```
 a = "0123 9809; 04323 ";
 b = a.split(' ').split(';')
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'split'
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
' 01234  ; 0123;0424 09234'.split(/\s|;/).filter(function (e) {
  return e.trim().length === 5;
});
```

in the example above `split` accepts a regular expression used for splitting the string. After that we use the [high-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) `filter`, which filters the input.

The is valid for [all modern browsers](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/).

Comment: +1 for functional style. It's worth pointing out that `Array.prototype.filter` is part of ECMAScript 5, so it won't work in IE8 or older.

Comment: Thanks! There is a link to the Kangax's ES5 compatibility table.

Answer (score 1):

`.split()` works on strings so that is why you are seeing the error - you are calling it on a string which returns an array, and they trying to call it again on the array. There are many ways to approach this.

I'd be tempted to take a short cut and replace all spaces with semicolons and then perform a single `.split(';')` to generate the array, and then use .filter() to filter out only those strings in the array that match the length you are looking for.